# How to communicate between two Unity apps with TCP?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, networkstream

**Update**

I figured out what the problem was.  I was trying to move too much data over TCP, and it was causing freeze-ups.  For some reason, this wasn't manifesting in the editor...who knows for what reason.  If anyone else stumbles upon this problem (in a program like Unity, where functions are looping constantly and data is always being processed), consider that you're moving too much irrelevant data.

**Original Post**

I've run into quite the problem, and I'm hoping I can receive some guidance.

In short, I'm wondering how to use TCP to communicate two Unity apps over the same computer.  I've gotten it functioning in editor, but when both apps are built, communication quickly breaks down.

This is really stumping me, because I don't understand why an app would work in the Editor environment, but not in the official build.

When I use TCP to communicate between two Unity apps (on the same computer), it works so long as one of them is kept in the Unity environment.  That is, if I build one app, and open the other in the Unity editor, TCP communication works flawlessly.

Here is some more background:  One of my apps is functioning as a User Interface, and the other is interfacing with a Looking Glass to provide a holographic display of in-game objects.  Originally, they were combined into one App - but I had a lot of trouble getting Unity's multidisplay support to function between two monitors of different resolutions.  Looking Glass factory even provides a prefab to do just this, but it is broken in the current SDK.  So I have resorted to using sockets to interface between two apps, one for each monitor.

I'm using C#'s TCP listener class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8

And TCP client class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Presently, the UI is acting as the TCPListener, and the application that produces holograms is the TCPClient.  Within each of these applications, I'm using two Queues - an IncomingMessages queue and an Outgoing Messages queue - which are global variables shared between the main thread and the networking thread.

TCP Listener:

```
private void Start()
{
    incomingMessages = new Queue();
    outgoingMessages = new Queue();

    Application.runInBackground = true;
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
    thread.Start();

    //stuff happens that's irrelevant to this question.  And then...   
}

void Receive()
{
    TcpListener server = null;

    try
    {
        // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
        Int32 port = 13000;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        // Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;

        // Enter the listening loop.

        Debug.Log("About to reenter main while in Server...");

        while (threadContinue)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection... ");

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.

            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Debug.Log("Connected!");

            data = null;

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Debug.Log("Received from Client: " + data);

                lock (this)

                incomingMessages.Enqueue(data);

                string response = supplyData();
                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                // Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                Debug.Log("Sent to Client: " + response);
            }

            // Shutdown and end connection
            client.Close();  
        }
    }


    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Debug.Log("SocketException: ");
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop listening for new clients.
        server.Stop();
    }
        Debug.Log("Exiting 'Receive'");
}
```

And here is the TCP Client.  It attempts to connect a regular intervals, and also whenever new data is available.  This is so that it can receive information from the server regularly and share new data whenever it is available:

```
void Start()
{
    //prepare networking
    Application.runInBackground = true;

    outgoingMessages = new Queue();
    incomingMessages = new Queue();

    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Connect));
    thread.Start();

    //stuff happens that's irrelevant to this question...
}

private void Connect()
{
    String server = "127.0.0.1";
    Int32 port = 13000;
    string message = "";
    while (threadContinue == true)
    {
        if (timeToConnect())
        {
            lastConnection = ourTime;
            if (outgoingMessages.Count > 0)
                message = outgoingMessages.Dequeue().ToString();
            else
                message = "Nothing to report.";

            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.

                client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Debug.Log("Sent to Server: " + message);


                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                lock (this)

                    incomingMessages.Enqueue(responseData);

                Debug.Log("Received from Server: " + responseData);


                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Debug.Log("ArgumentNullException: ");
                Debug.Log(e);

                outgoingMessages.Enqueue(message);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.Log("SocketException: ");
                Debug.Log(e);
                outgoingMessages.Enqueue(message);
            }
        }
    }
}


private bool timeToConnect()
{
    if ((ourTime - lastConnection > NETWORK_DELAY) || (outgoingMessages.Count > 0))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Instantiated in separate threads so that Unity's main thread can continue unhindered.

Again - it works in Editor, but when I build it, it breaks.

Comment: are you getting a specific error? maybe something about the port not being available?

Comment: Could you please add **your** implementation code

Comment: Need your code. Need your errors. Need detail. How are the ports allocated? Are both instances of the program competing for the same port in prod?

Comment: I'll add some code, hold on.  It is using queues.  There are no errors in editor - it is only when I build the applications that they start to break.

That's an important detail, just to make sure no one missed it.  The TCP works fine when one app is still in editor.

Comment: @chapter12 Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Ruzihm  Okay, I've added code to the question.  Let me know if you need more information, since I think the behavior is in there, main code in question, and the problem.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I've added code.  I'll see if I can locate the logbook for exported apps...in editor, though, there are no errors.

The ports are located as you can see in the code.  Do they need to be allocated any further, that you can tell?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: @derHugo I've added it

Comment: afaik you can't use `Debug.Log` in a thread .... and you should consider using [`ConcurrentQueue<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) here since they are thread save without using `lock`

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the tip.  I'll keep that in mind.  Everything seems to be working now...as it turns out, it wasn't some mystical, untraceable, under-the-hood problem...but just something simple, like it always is!  yarg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I figured out what the problem was. I was trying to move too much data over TCP, and it was causing freeze-ups. For some reason, this wasn't manifesting in the editor...just in the exported app.  Who knows for what reason. If anyone else stumbles upon this problem...where you're bypassing Unity's multidisplay functionality by building multiple apps that communicate over network...consider that you're burdening your queues with too much data.